# Clear multiple ASP Textboxes using Javascript on Button Click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to clear data of multiple ASP Textboxes on clicking **Clear** button.
I was trying with one textbox initially. It is clearing the the textbox data on button-click, but it is also calling the **Page_Load** method. I want to clear textboxes without calling **Page_Load** method.

Here is the code, I tried:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function Clear() {
                        document.getElementById("<%=txt.ClientID %>").value = "";
                return true;
            }
   </script>
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="click" OnClientClick="return Clear();" />    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Return false in your function or add return false to the end of your OnClientClick declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid page load by changing the return of your function:

```
function Clear() {
    document.getElementById("<%=txt.ClientID %>").value = "";
    return false;
}
```

And you can use classes to clear multiple textboxes, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" CssClass="txts"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server" CssClass="txts"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt3" runat="server" CssClass="txts"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt4" runat="server" CssClass="txts"></asp:TextBox>
```

And the JS:

```
function Clear() {
    var txts = document.getElementsByClassName('txts');

    for (var i = 0; i < txts.length; i++)
        txts[i].value = '';

    return false;
}
```

Hope it helps!